# Find the limit of its fractions!

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, fractions

$\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}$
$\newcommand{\F}{\mathbb{F}}$
$\newcommand{\coloneqq}{:=}$

If it exists find the value of:
$$1 + \cfrac{1}{1 + \cfrac{1}{1 + \cfrac{1}{1 + \ddots}}}$$
i.e. the limit of the sequence $(x_{n})_{n \in \N}$ with:
$$x_{1} \coloneqq 1 \hspace{0.5cm}\text{and}\hspace{0.5cm} x_{n+1} \coloneqq 1 + \frac{1}{x_{n}}$$

May you help with hints to begin?

Comment: The classical representation of the golden ratio

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If the sequence has a limit, then it must hold that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} x_{n+1} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + \frac 1{x_n} \right) = 1 + \frac{1}{\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n}.
$$